# laravel install on bluehost - 500 error despite multiple methods of install

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, deployment

So I have tried this method here: [official laravel news blog](https://laravel-news.com/subfolder-install)

That didn't work. And I don't even think that method is complete based on further research I have done. Based on that research, I have also in addition to changing the index.php file in the public directory attempted to work with .htaccess, updated the server.php, and changed file permissions for the storage folder to 777 (read write and ex)

Still no luck. 500 server errors. I have ssh access to the server, and have composer working and up to date. I have installed laravel via composer, changed file permission via ssh, and still no luck there. I have manually uploaded a fresh laravel install to the server and tried all these methods, no luck there. I have kept the application all together, and also broken it up so only the public folder is in my public_html and everything links up past that. I have tried everything I could find on the internet.

So now I am wondering if it is simply a bluehost issue. Any help or insight would be appreciated! At this point I could care less about security I just want to get the app running. I can worry about security later. And yes, it has to be on bluehost. Laravel 5.4. Composer version 1.4.0  Apache 2.2.31 PHP 5.4.43

Let's start with this:
file structure is basic laravel fresh install
storage folder set to 777
And we can work from here?

Comment: 500 means internal server error, you need to check the web server logs for more information on the specific error.

Comment: I cleared the log and tried to reload the page a few times and it is still empty. I am looking at the error_log under public_html

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing? Turn on the ability to see the errors so you can let us know.

Could be something simple like generating a key with php artisan (that seems to be a popular gotcha)

Comment: @Hanny my .env file does have an app_key and app_debug is set to true right now. The error in my browser is "currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"    Is that what you mean by turn on ability to see errors?

Comment: `Laravel 5.4` required `PHP >= 5.6.4`.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU @AmrAly THIS WORKED

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, but ***do not set things to 777*** - that is **terribly** insecure. Read up on proper security and don't change default settings unless it's absolute last resort or you know *exactly* what you're doing. If something says it *needs* 777 permissions? It's probably hacky or junky - that is *very rarely* a viable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel `5.4 required` `PHP >= 5.6.4`