# Laravel - Error page is blank after update from 5.3 to 5.4

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have updated Laravel from `5.3` to `5.4`. Error pages are white and do not display an error after update. I am using a local server. The specifications:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Nginx/1.9.15
PHP 5.6.11
```

I read the this question ([Laravel blank white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678360/laravel-blank-white-screen)) and I have tried solutions:

```
# Group Writable (Group, User Writable)
$ sudo chmod -R gu+w storage

# World-writable (Group, User, Other Writable)
$ sudo chmod -R guo+w storage
```

And other solutions have been proposed. But the problem persists!

Also, Application debuggin in `.env` and `config/app.php` is `true`.

**Who can help?**

Comment: What do the log files say

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code?, where are the errors supposed to happen?, also check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/blank-white-screen

Comment: @Ohgodwhy In this file errors are recorded. `[2017-04-07 21:08:27] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: image' in /home/ali/www/brandmashhoor/storage/framework/views/57345fd9a58712cb3d79cd32e59c661578d51e7f.php:30
`

Comment: @OmarTarek This problem is not related to the type code.

Comment: review this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680088/laravel-install-on-bluehost-500-error-despite-multiple-methods-of-install/42680785#42680785)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After update your laravel you may clear all your cache and your compiled page. Try to do this:

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: I will announce the results after testing. Thanks you.

Comment: The problem was not solved by using these codes. I want to do again update might fix that.

Comment: you also can try to delete your compiled.php files... worth a try cause sometimes the clear compiled command does not work always...